# JS: initiate search when fill input with script

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to transfer the music list from an app to Spotify.
I got an array of songs (like [`Hold On To Me Placebo`, `Come Undone Placebo`] etc.) and tried to automate the liking of songs in this way:

```
let inputField = document.getElementsByClassName('_2f8ed265fb69fb70c0c9afef329ae0b6-scss')[0];
let menu = document.querySelectorAll('react-contextmenu')[0];
let like = document.querySelectorAll('react-contextmenu-item')[1];

function addSong() {
    for (song of arrOfSongs) {

    inputField.value = song;
    menu.click();
    like.click();
    inputField.value = '';

    }
}

addSong();
```

There are 2 problems:

1. When the value is changed in the input field, the search doesn't work: the content on the page stays the same as before filling it;
2. Even if I type the name of some song by myself, it returns the values of `menu` and `like` variables as undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1: it's unclear what you mean with "the search doesn't work: the content on the page stays the same as before filling it". If you mean the value of the input, this happens because you first put there a value of a song, then 2 rows later you clear it with the instruction `inputField.value = '';` . If you remove that everything will be updated.

Problem 2, probably `react-contextmenu` and `react-contextmenu-item` are class names and the `querySelectorAll` function works with **selectors** (see here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors ). In this case you should change the assignment to the menu and like variables in this way

```
let menu = document.querySelectorAll('.react-contextmenu')[0];
let like = document.querySelectorAll('.react-contextmenu-item')[1];
```

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/98jnb3q4/)